# Books on pseudocomplemented lattices and Heyting algebras

Tags: reference-request, lattice-orders, book-recommendation

I was wondering if anyone knows a good reference for pseudocomplemented lattices and/or Heyting algebras. Ideally, it should be something like Givant & Halmos's *Introduction to Boolean Algebras*, but I'd set for something less comprehensive.

Comment: There's a chapter or two about it it in Sørensen and Urzyczyn *[Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.17.7385)*.

Comment: @MJD - Thanks for the interesting reference. I glanced through the book, and they seem to be interested in Heyting algebras more as tools to develop an appropriate setting for intuitionistic logic. I'd rather see something that expounded Heyting algebras for their own sake, so to speak, rather like some books deal with Boolean algebras independently of any connection with propositional logic.

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly what you are looking for. That is why I only posted a comment.